# Positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, transpose

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix is it true that also $A+A^T$ is positive definite?
If it is true, how to prove it? I try to employ the definition using eigenvalues but i'm not able to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linearity, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ is pos. def. so we know that: $x^T Ax>0, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$. Let $B = A + A^T$ then we want to know if:

$$x^TBx>0\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}.$$

Plug in $B = A + A^T$:

$$x^TBx = x^T(A + A^T)x = x^TAx + x^TA^Tx = x^TAx + (x^TAx)^T = x^TAx + x^TAx>0\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}.$$

In the last step we used that $x^TAx$ is a scalar (see answer by @0XLR)

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seet it. It was so simple!

Comment: Caution: we don't know whether $A=A^T$ : the asker hasn't said that $A$ is a **symmetric** positive definite matrix ... (or he/she has forgotten to mention it because some people considered this property as implicitly said)

Comment: @JeanMarie where have I used the symmetric property?

Comment: On the last line : $x^TA^Tx=x^TAx$

Comment: @JeanMarie See my last sentence and the answer below

Comment: I understand. Don't you think that a more didactic way to write it would have been to insert $x^TAx + x^TA^Tx = \color{red}{x^TAx + (x^TAx)^T}= x^TAx + x^TAx>0$ ?

Comment: I will edit the step in between, although with the Hint below, I think it is a bit redundant

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $x^T A^T x$ is a scalar so $x^T A^T x = (x^T A^T x)^T = x^T A x$.